# multilevel json reading in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
{
      "result": {
        {
          "bitfinex:bfxbtc": {
            "price": {
              "last": 0.00067133,
              "high": 0.0006886,
              "low": 0.00066753,
              "change": {
                "percentage": -0.02351996,
                "absolute": -1.6169972e-05
              }
            },
            "volume":84041.625
          },
          "bitfinex:bfxusd": {
            ...
          },
          "bitfinex:btcusd": {
            ...
          },
          ...
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm able to parse data until result `console.log(d.result.bitfinex:bfxbtc);` but not able to read after writing `bitfinex:btcusd` its giving me error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Do I need to use recursion?

Comment: The error message said that you forgot adding `)` character in somewhere. Check again to fix.

Comment: its because of `bitfinex:bfxbtc` specifically `:` if I remove `:` that error disappears

Comment: You can try again with `console.log(d.result["bitfinex:bfxbtc"]);`

Comment: its showing `undefined`

Comment: So, you fixed the error? Then try again with the parent: `console.log(d.result);`. If there is no "bitfinex:bfxbtc" property, it should be another problem.

Comment: that's the question, how to access "bitfinex:bfxbtc" property,

Answer (score 1):

your json format is invalid please first format it and then use it like this.

```js
var a = { "result": {
        "bitfinex:bfxbtc": {
          "price": {
            "last": 0.00067133,
            "high": 0.0006886,
            "low": 0.00066753,
            "change": {
              "percentage": -0.02351996,
              "absolute": -1.6169972e-05
            }
          },
          "volume": 84041.625
        },
        "bitfinex:bfxusd": {
          
        },
        "bitfinex:btcusd": {
          
        },
        
      }
    };
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = a.result["bitfinex:bfxbtc"].price.last;
```

```html
<div id="show"></div>
```

when I try to validate your json get this error:

> Error: Parse error on line 2:
>   {   "result": {     {           "bitfinex:bfxbt
>   ---------------^
>   Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{'